# AWS localhost with whatever port

Tags: node.js, api, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance thats running an apache server that I can access just fine. However I also have three api's that I am running on that same EC2 instance. these run on ports such as 3007 and I've allowed access to that port and my front end try to use localhost with those associated ports. 
   Now when I start those API's they connect fine to my external resources such as a database however my front end can't connect to them. Without having to use an additional service such as AWS api gateway, why might it have an issue connecting?

Comment: Have you allowed incoming/outgoing access from port 3007 from all IPs? Check your security group.

Comment: Hey @SamyokNepal thanks for responding. Yes I did allow access to those ports as a custom TCP rule to all ports

Comment: On the front end, are you calling localhost or your EC2 ip?

Comment: On the front end I am calling the localhost , also the front end is running on that same ec2 instance @SamyokNepal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your problem arises from the fact that you are calling `localhost` instead of your EC2 IP/domain name.

When you call `localhost`, that means whatever computer you are at. For backend, `localhost` is encouraged since you are on the same computer. But on the frontend, your website tries to go to `localhost:3007`, which is the client computer. You need to change it to either `ec2-<<your EC2 public IP here>>.compute-1.amazonaws.com` or your EC2 Public IP.

You can find these here:

[image: EC2 DNS area]

Comment: So it appears to be working, because I screwed around with the linux system and im no linux guru I had to create a new EC2 and start transferring stuff over. I got one of the api's over and launched it. Using Postman I was able to connect with the api through the EC2 IP so im assuming once I get everything else set up that it should work. thanks @Samyok Nepal

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you so late--but great!